# Can we automate APIs usiing testCafe?

Tags: api, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

Caw we automate APIs using testCafe? I have a requirement to automate both Web & APIs together, I mean after doing some actions on the UI, I need to test relevant APIs.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand well your needs but if you want to check the result of an api request I guess you'll need the `RequestLogger` : a hook you can add to your test on some specific api's urls and then in your test you will be able to check what the request contains.

Documentation here: https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/intercepting-http-requests/logging-http-requests.html

Comment: Since TestCafe version 1.20.0 you can use the [`t.request` method](https://testcafe.io/documentation/403981/reference/test-api/testcontroller/request) to send API request in your test and check its response.